# JasperReports Font extension not working on Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have created a report using Jaspersoft Studio. I've used a font name FMBindumathi. I've generated the font-extension and when I'm previewing inside the Studio and export as pdf it works fine. But after that I've include it in eclipse spring mvc project and it's not work.

Here's a preview of at JSS:
[image: Generated from Jasper studio]

But when I'm using the compiled report from my eclipse project it shows this.
[image: Generated from java code]

Here is my java code to preview this report on browser

```
 JRDataSource conn=new JREmptyDataSource();
         InputStream st = request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("assets/repaymentsheet.jasper");
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(st);
        //Parameters as Map to be passed to Jasper

           HashMap<String,Object> hmParams=new HashMap<String,Object>();
           hmParams.put("address", address);
           hmParams.put("name", name);
           hmParams.put("amount", amount+"");
           hmParams.put("vno", agreement);
 byte[] bytes = null;
    bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport,parameters,conn);
    resp.reset();
    resp.resetBuffer();
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    resp.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    ServletOutputStream ouputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
    ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    ouputStream.flush();
    ouputStream.close();
```

Please help me with this issue

Comment: Did you add the jar with font to cp? Did you check the same code with simple test (junit or simple console application)? Did you try to debug to check the if the font is available for JR engine?

Comment: Yes I've added the jar file. And my font is installed on my machine too.